# Ubuntu Apache PHP - Create and write to an Excel Document

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpexcel

I have heard of [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) inorder to work with excel documents in PHP. However do I require MS Office on the Ubuntu System inorder to work and serve excel documents? Or can the PHP Excel extension work ad hoc with serving excel documents in any system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel is pure PHP, it has no requirement to access MS Office in any way

From the readme of the [PHPExcel repo on github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

> PHPExcel is a library written in **pure PHP** and providing a set of classes that allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML, ... This project is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.

**Requirements**

- PHP version 5.2.0 or higher
- PHP extension php_zip enabled (required if you need PHPExcel to handle .xlsx .ods or .gnumeric files)
- PHP extension php_xml enabled
- PHP extension php_gd2 enabled (optional, but required for exact column width autocalculation)

Comment: So to clarify I don't need MS office on the server I use this on?

Comment: To clarify.... there is absolutely no need to have MS Office on the server

Comment: @SadCRUDDeveloper Did you created a phpexcel file in Ubuntu? please answer.
i'm now struggling to create it